# How to override font familly in Django 4.2?

Tags: python, django

Django 4.2 release notes:

> The admin’s font stack now prefers system UI fonts and no longer
> requires downloading fonts. Additionally, CSS variables are available
> to more easily override the default font families.

I noticed that the font familly of the admin panel changed from :

```
font-family: Roboto, "Lucida Grande", "DejaVu Sans", "Bitstream Vera Sans", Verdana, Arial, sans-serif;
```

To

```
font-family: var(--font-family-primary);
--font-family-primary: -apple-system, BlinkMacSystemFont, "Segoe UI", system-ui, Roboto, "Helvetica Neue", Arial, sans-serif, "Apple Color Emoji", "Segoe UI Emoji", "Segoe UI Symbol", "Noto Color Emoji";
```

How can I customize `font-family-primary` and make it use Roboto as before ?